# C++ IEnumerable<int>=class->method(); in WinForms

Tags: .net, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++-cli, ienumerable

I want the C++ equivalent to the following C#.

```cs
List<int> k = myclass.method().ToList();
```

In my standard C++ WinForms application I have tried the following:

```cpp
IEnumerable<int>^ m=    myclass->method();
```

I get the following error:

> C2872 IEnumerable ambiguous symbol

Please help me understand and resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `IEnumerable`s -- one in `System::Collections`, and one in `System::Collections::Generic`.

Somehow you have both in scope (probably with using directives), so you'll need to either remove said using directives or fully qualify the type name:

```
System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<int>^ m = myclass->method();
```